# Question regarding ‘ Either/Neither’

Tags: grammar

She put forward two proposals, .......... of which didn’t make any sense to the participants in the summit.

The answer for this question in grammar exercises is ‘either’. I am doubtful whether to use either or neither. Can any one clarify this with reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using Either**

> She put forward two proposals, either of which didn’t make any sense
>   to the participants in the summit.

**Using Neither**

> She put forward two proposals, neither of which make any sense to the
>   participants in the summit.

As *neither is already the negative of either*, you will omit the other negative word (didn't) if using it.

The presence of the negative **didn't** makes EITHER the right answer.

Comment: Thanks. Is ‘either’ a pronoun in the quoted sentence?

Comment: Yes, as it is being used for a noun (proposals)